# How to split API call answer into multiple embeds?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So i'm pretty new to coding and am trying to create a simple bot that would make an API call and post the result in a discord channel. I managed to get all the info i need but it can't post it because it exceeds characters limit.

Do you have any idea how i could split the results into multiple embeds?

- Here's the API i'm making my call to: https://api.howrare.is/v0.1/drops (getting all results for the day)
- Here's my code: https://srcshare.io/?id=62921e259ba7e81e5891a380

Thank you so much for your help <3

Answer (score 0):

Discord embed's description are limited to 4096 characters, if you really want to post your text into a direct message, you can divide your text into other texts which are 4096 long, and post as many embeds as required.

However, you also can use the `fs` package to write your JSON response into a json file, and then post the file, Discord will automatically interprets the content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would go by making an array of embeds and then pushing each embed to the array then replying with the embeds. Also know that you can send maximum of 10 embeds per reply.

```js
const embeds = [];

finals.forEach((final) => embeds.push(new MessageEmbed().setDescription(`\nName: ${final.name}\nTime: ${final.time}\nPrice: ${final.price}\nNft_count: ${final.nft_count}\nExtra: ${final.extra}\nTwitter: ${final.twitter}\nDiscord: ${final.discord}\nWebsite: ${final.website}`)));

interaction.reply({ embeds });
```

Comment: This look really good but leaves me with more than 10 embeds :/
Would there be a way to have each embed display like 5 complete elements instead of 1 per embed?

Comment: Or maybe a way to post the others (after 10) in a new post or something?

Comment: How many embeds do you expect to have?

Comment: There is not really an expected number of embeds, it really vary each days depending on how many new NFT drops there is that day.
You can see upcoming drops here : https://howrare.is/drops so you'll have a better idea of what i'm tryin to achieve maybe.
Thank you guys for your help, very much appreciated and helpful <3